# User Can't See A Record From SOQL RESULT

Tags: apex, soql, sharing

I have a Lightning Page generated based on SOQL for different objects. The System Admins can see everything just fine. The other users cannot. I tried adding '...With Sharing...' to the APEX Class, but nothing has changed. Is there something else that would stop a user from seeing records, if pre-Lightning Page, they had permission to see records created by others? Outside of this Lightning Page I've created, their sharing/permissions are working fine. I'm assuming it's something in the APEX Class, but am unsure what. I even had the standard 'Info' user create a record, but that 'Info' user can't see it.

[image]

Comment: `with sharing` enforces those rules, you'd want to use `without sharing`, (rules meaning permissions and profiles)

Comment: @EricSSH looks like without sharing is giving me the same non-results

Comment: turn off your persistent browser caching in your `Session Setting`, it might be cached and not recognizing the changes yet

Comment: I turned that off that setting. Cleared a second browser and opened the Dev environment in that new browser. Still didn't show. I created a RLC2_Class and used that as the controller for a few of the blocks. But it's still not showing for non-Admins. Not sure where to go with this one.

Comment: Have you used the browser inspector to look at the returned data from the call to RLC_Class.fetchRecs to see if you are actually getting results? It may be a rendering rather than querying issue.

Comment: Did you explicitly grant the user access to the `RLC_Class` class? In lightning, users must be explicitly given permission to access top level classes for the components in their pages.

Comment: @PhilW Verified that it's not a rendering issue. No data is being fetched.

Comment: @MarkPond success! Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't know that. If you'd like to post as an answer, I would be more than happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you explicitly grant the user access to the `RLC_Class` class? In lightning, users must be explicitly given permission to access top level classes for the components in their pages.

This is changed from past releases where implicit access was granted.

Additional information about granting access and the critical update which brought this change can be found in a few places:

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_security.htm
2. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm
3. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/breezing-through-the-upcoming-auraenabled-critical-update.html
4. https://www.codescience.com/blog/2020/an-isvs-guide-to-the-auraenabled-critical-update